# jQuery ui resizable can't expand elements to the left or the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to add resizable event to some elements, but I noticed a weird thing while I was trying to expand an element to the left or top.

I have a div with class **.limit** which is the **containment** for my resizable elements.

my resizable elements are wrapped inside a **div.content**

If you try to expand an element to the left or top you will notice that it won't allows you, but it's possible to expand it to the right and bottom until you get to the containment (**div.limit**)

This is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mody5/s0yo16ek/5/

and this is the code :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="limit">
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="resizable">Navbar example</h1>
      <p class="resizable">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.limit{
    width: 600px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.content{
    width:500px;
    margin: 18px;
    padding:10px;
    background: orange;
}
.resizable{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
 $(".resizable").resizable({
        containment: '.limit',
        handles: "n, e, s, w"       
 });
```

Comment: I can't get the resizing to work at all.

Comment: @BSMP sorry it was an error from jsfiddle, I corrected the link : http://jsfiddle.net/mody5/s0yo16ek/5/

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like a bug. Looking at jquery source code, you can see as soon as coordinates of element goes in negative left, it resets left to 0, not taking care of the offset. Since your element is relative, position is 0, but it doesn't mean it can't go in negative if you want.
You can modify jquery-ui for your needs. For example, rewriting resizable part that deals with containment takes care of the left issue. Now maybe there's another way, and this is not really a proper solution, but still:

```
$.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "containment", {

    start: function(event, ui) {
        var that = $(this).data("resizable"), o = that.options, el = that.element;
        var oc = o.containment, ce = (oc instanceof $) ? oc.get(0) : (/parent/.test(oc)) ? el.parent().get(0) : oc;
        eoffset=that.element.offset()//at start get offset of the element
        if (!ce) return;

        that.containerElement = $(ce);

        if (/document/.test(oc) || oc == document) {
            that.containerOffset = { left: 0, top: 0 };
            that.containerPosition = { left: 0, top: 0 };

            that.parentData = {
                element: $(document), left: 0, top: 0,
                width: $(document).width(), height: $(document).height() || document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight
            };
        }


        else {
            var element = $(ce), p = [];
            $([ "Top", "Right", "Left", "Bottom" ]).each(function(i, name) { p[i] = num(element.css("padding" + name)); });

            that.containerOffset = element.offset();
            that.containerPosition = element.position();
            that.containerSize = { height: (element.innerHeight() - p[3]), width: (element.innerWidth() - p[1]) };

            var co = that.containerOffset, ch = that.containerSize.height,  cw = that.containerSize.width,
                        width = ($.ui.hasScroll(ce, "left") ? ce.scrollWidth : cw ), height = ($.ui.hasScroll(ce) ? ce.scrollHeight : ch);

            that.parentData = {
                element: ce, left: co.left, top: co.top, width: width, height: height
            };
        }
    },

    resize: function(event, ui) {

        var that = $(this).data("resizable"), o = that.options,
                ps = that.containerSize, co = that.containerOffset, cs = that.size, cp = that.position,
                pRatio = that._aspectRatio || event.shiftKey, cop = { top:0, left:0 }, eo = that.element.offset(), ce = that.containerElement;//add eo variable to get offset while resizing

        if (ce[0] != document && (/static/).test(ce.css('position'))) cop = co;

        if (cp.left < (that._helper ? co.left : co.left-eoffset.left+that.originalPosition.left)) {//instead of validating if position is lower than 0, checks that offset of left is lower than containment offset
            console.log('hey')
            that.size.width = that.size.width + (that._helper ? (that.position.left - co.left) : (that.position.left - cop.left));
            if (pRatio) that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
            that.position.left = o.helper ? co.left : co.left-eoffset.left+that.originalPosition.left;//if it's lower than containment offset, set it to containment offset minus start position offset plus original position offset.

        }

        if (cp.top < (that._helper ? co.top : 0)) {
            that.size.height = that.size.height + (that._helper ? (that.position.top - co.top) : that.position.top);
            if (pRatio) that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
            that.position.top = that._helper ? co.top : 0;
        }

        that.offset.left = 50;
        that.offset.top = that.parentData.top+that.position.top;

        var woset = Math.abs( (that._helper ? that.offset.left - cop.left : (that.offset.left - cop.left)) + that.sizeDiff.width ),
                    hoset = Math.abs( (that._helper ? that.offset.top - cop.top : (that.offset.top - co.top)) + that.sizeDiff.height );

        var isParent = that.containerElement.get(0) == that.element.parent().get(0),
            isOffsetRelative = /relative|absolute/.test(that.containerElement.css('position'));

        if(isParent && isOffsetRelative) woset -= that.parentData.left;

        if (woset + that.size.width >= that.parentData.width) {
            that.size.width = that.parentData.width - woset;
            if (pRatio) that.size.height = that.size.width / that.aspectRatio;
        }

        if (hoset + that.size.height >= that.parentData.height) {
            that.size.height = that.parentData.height - hoset;
            if (pRatio) that.size.width = that.size.height * that.aspectRatio;
        }
    },

    stop: function(event, ui){

        var that = $(this).data("resizable"), o = that.options, cp = that.position,
                co = that.containerOffset, cop = that.containerPosition, ce = that.containerElement;

        var helper = $(that.helper), ho = helper.offset(), w = helper.outerWidth() - that.sizeDiff.width, h = helper.outerHeight() - that.sizeDiff.height;

        if (that._helper && !o.animate && (/relative/).test(ce.css('position')))
            $(this).css({ left: ho.left - cop.left - co.left, width: w, height: h });

        if (that._helper && !o.animate && (/static/).test(ce.css('position')))
            $(this).css({ left: ho.left - cop.left - co.left, width: w, height: h });

    }
});
```

Very heavy jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmm3p1be/1/

Comment: OMG! your jsfiddle works fine, but wait wait... what did you change exactly ? should I change the code inside the jquery-ui.js or just add the above code to override the jquery-ui code ? I am using version 1.11.4

Comment: you can try replacing the part of jquery ui that starts with $.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "containment",{. I haven't touched anything else. But I think it's from version 1.9, so it may not work. And even if it works, it's a bit of a hack, it may cause other problems. But you can try.

Comment: what is the line you touched exactly in the above code ?

Comment: see edit, I've commented the changes I've made. There's one in variable declaration in start part, one in variable declaration in resize part and a bit lower where there's an if for left position I changed the condition and the last line. With same logic, top issue could probably be resolved as well.

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work in my computer :/ also now your jsfiddle when you resize to the right it doesn't work correctly for the right size, I am a little confusing :(

Comment: Well, as I said it's a bit of a hack. I really think it's a bug, but maybe there are reason why it was designed that way in the first place. That said the problem with right resize could probably be fixed keeping same logic. But then the question is, is it really worth it?